# I'd like to know how to use the verb 'change

Tags: word-usage

I'm comfortable saying like this:

> 1. The way people listen to music has changed a lot over the years.

but how about this?

> 2. Many things have changed in the way people listen to music.

In the same way I'm comfortable saying:

> 3. Banks have changed a lot over the years.

Then how about this?

> 4. Many things have changed in banks

I'd like to know if there's a difference in meaning between #1,3 and #2,4

Comment: Why do you think there might be a problem with 2 and 4?

Comment: You want to know how to use the verb 'change' - I'm afraid, it's too broad a topic to explain. Secondly, 'things' is an umbrella term applied to anything you want to say, including 'the way music is listened to'. Overall, the question is a bit confusing!

Comment: Both forms are grammatically correct, but they say slightly different things. What exactly is your question about them?

Comment: I think your real problem may not be about the verb *change*, but it's more about rephrasing a sentence with "Many things <verb> in <realm>."

Comment: yes @DamkerngT. that's what it is

Comment: I'd just like to know if there's a difference in meaning  so I can say anything I want. I'm sorry If I sounded like I want it to be rephrased. TT

Comment: @jihoon Don't worry. No need to fell sorry, at all. I take it that you want to have more alternatives to express what you want in your everyday life better and more precise. I suggested the pattern "Many things <verb> in <topic>." because it looks like it's the essence of your question. (On second thought, I think "topic" is a better word.) I believe that there is a set of verbs that allow you to use #2 and #4, but I have no clear picture of them in mind. (FWIW, I think these are possible *be*, *become*, *change*, *exist*, *happen*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two formations say slightly different things. The first form ('*A thing* has changed a lot') says that something has changed a great deal, whereas the second  ('Many things have changed in *a thing*') says that it has changed multiple times or in multiple ways.

If a thing changed a lot, but in only one way (say, the weather going from very hot to very cold, but otherwise remaining the same), you might say that it has changed a lot, but would probably not say that many things had changed in it.